# Php mail() on OS X localhost keeps getting rejected as spam

Tags: php, macos, email, sendmail

I would like to send mails with this little php script on OS X 10.9.

```
mail($_POST['to'], $_POST['subject'], $_POST['message'], "From: " . $_POST['from']);
```

The method returns true but the message never arrives at my inbox :( I've locked at the error messages from postfix and they tell me that it's blocked because of spam.

```
Mar  6 11:30:38 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/pickup[69960]: BB98E14DD64A: uid=70 from=<_www>
Mar  6 11:30:38 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/cleanup[70313]: BB98E14DD64A: message-id=<20140306103038.BB98E14DD64A@xxxs-    MacBook-Pro.local>
Mar  6 11:30:38 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/qmgr[69961]: BB98E14DD64A: from=<_www@xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local>, size=384,     nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/smtp[70315]: BB98E14DD64A: to=<xxx@xxx.com>, relay=mx3.me.com.akadns.net[17.172.    34.65]:25, delay=0.67, delays=0/0/0.53/0.14, dsn=5.7.1, status=bounced (host mx3.me.com.akadns.net[17.172.34.65] said: 550 5.7.1      Mail from IP 95.91.221.96 was rejected due to listing in Spamhaus PBL. For details please see http://www.spamhaus.org/query/bl?ip=95.    91.221.96 : xxx@xxx.com (in reply to RCPT TO command))
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/cleanup[70313]: 8C52414DD64D: message-id=<20140306103039.8C52414DD64D@xxxs-    MacBook-Pro.local>
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/bounce[70316]: BB98E14DD64A: sender non-delivery notification: 8C52414DD64D
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/qmgr[69961]: 8C52414DD64D: from=<>, size=2669, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/qmgr[69961]: BB98E14DD64A: removed
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/local[70317]: 8C52414DD64D: to=<_www@xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local>, relay=local,     delay=0, delays=0/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered to mailbox)
Mar  6 11:30:39 xxxs-MacBook-Pro.local postfix/qmgr[69961]: 8C52414DD64D: removed
```

How can i circumvent this?

Cheers Daniel

Answer (score 2):

The IP is listed in spamhaus:

```
Mail from IP 95.91.221.96 was rejected due to listing in Spamhaus PBL.
```

> The Spamhaus PBL is a DNSBL database of end-user IP address ranges which should not be delivering unauthenticated SMTP email to any Internet mail server except those provided for specifically by an ISP for that customer's use. The PBL helps networks enforce their Acceptable Use Policy for dynamic and non-MTA customer IP ranges.

This simply means that you are using the IP from your ISP for delivering e-mail. The ISP actively prohibits this to prevent their customers from sending spam. The most simple solution is to use the SMTP server provided by your ISP. You can configure this in your php.ini as the default server instead of localhost:

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = mail.yourISP.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25
```

There are a number of reasons not to use the local mail() function from PHP for sending mail. The best known alternative is [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer). This code has it's own built-in SMTP client for sending mail in the most proper way. You can easily integrate this in your software to furthermore prevent your mail from being marked as spam.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i need smtp authentication for that, right?

Comment: it depends on your ISP. My ISP allows all mail from the ip-addresses connected to their network, and thus no smtp authentication is required.